# mysql query returns two separate arrays

Tags: mysql, node.js

When I do the code below I get two separate arrays with info but what i really want is to get it into one array

The code:

``` order_ids.forEach( id => {
                    var sql_order = ``SELECT * FROM wordpress.wp58_postmeta where post_id=${id} and meta_key='_order_total'``;
                    con.query(sql_order, function(err,result){
                        if(err)throw err;
                        console.log(result);
                    });
                }); ```

The result:

`[ RowDataPacket {
    meta_id: 65960,
    post_id: 5445,
    meta_key: '_order_total',
    meta_value: '900.00' } ]
[ RowDataPacket {
    meta_id: 66074,
    post_id: 5449,
    meta_key: '_order_total',
    meta_value: '269.10' } ]`

Comment: What result do you *want* to get?

Comment: I want the two separate arrays to be one

Comment: These are actually associative arrays, like `key: value`. You cannot two identical keys in the same array, and keys are the same in both array : how to you want to manage this when merging the two arrays ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your current code, you are executing the query for each item in `order_ids` and that is why you get multiple arrays. If you want to get one array with all rows you should do something like this

```
var sql_order = `SELECT * FROM wordpress.wp58_postmeta where post_id in (?) and meta_key='_order_total`;
con.query(sql_order, [order_ids] , function(err,result){
                    if(err)throw err;
                    console.log(result);
                });
```

Comment: order_ids is a array with integers therefore i used a foreach loop to make the query beacuse i got x values in order_ids. Your solution only got me the first value.

Comment: you need a nested array as second parameter to `query` then. I have updated the answer